# How to join audio tracks into a single audiobook?

Tags: itunes, audio

I am looking for a solution to join entire CD to a single audio file, preferably with chapterizing functionality.

Usually, [Join Toghether](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/jointogether.php) should do the job but this solution doesn't work anymore with Lion and I am looking for a solution that works with Lion.

I mention that most of my files are in AAC Lossless format and I don't want to convert them to something worse. I tried Audiobook Builder but it seams to not be able to build lossless files.

Answer (score 2):

Rogue Amoeba's [Fission](http://rogueamoeba.com/fission/) will do what you want. It costs US $39 but it has a limited trial demo you can download. It is a lightweight lossless audio editor. The publisher reports no compatibility problems with Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for this are documented on my blog:
http://underdesign.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/quick-and-dirty-free-joining-of-mp3-files-on-a-mac/

Uses open-source or free software, and the command line.

Comment: I appreciate the use of free software but the solution will work only with MP3 and will be missing all the meta information. There are ways to create audio-books that keep all information from the original songs.

Answer (score 1):

My personal choice for all audio editing is [Sound Studio](http://www.felttip.com/ss/). I acquired it in its Freeverse days, but it is now distributed by its developers, Felttip. It's priced at $29.99, and is available on the Mac App Store, with a 15-use demo download available from the Felttip site.

It's only now, while checking links for this answer, that I see it's now reached Version 4 (I've been using 3 for some time, and do not recall receiving notification of upgrade availability). My experience with Version 3 has been unchanged since upgrading to Lion.